# Function of 'Max Width' of Crossing Rectangular Bars

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

*(Looking at the Visual Example image below should greatly help with your understanding of my problem)*

I'm trying to find the function for the increase of the 'maximum width' of two (identically sized, although their width is all that matters here) rectangular bars, with respect to a changing angle between these two bars.

I say 'maximum width' because I'm not sure what to call it, in the Visual Example it is the red line. When rotating the bars, the pivot point is the exact centre of the red line, so at 180 or 0 degrees, the bars are perfectly aligned on top of each other, so the 'maximum width' is the width of the bars naturally.

[Visual Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkp7Q.png)

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CK5fn.png)

This is a quick Desmos graph of my (very roughly) found data points, the x values are obviously the angle between the rectangular bars, and the y-values represent the 'max width' of the bars (both bars have width of 1 unit). Black line is the closest function I've got, seems to indicate the real function is not a simple exponential.

I'm trying to find this function for a small coding project of mine, and if it is too complicated, I'll have to settle with the inaccurate exponential I quickly came up with due to performance reasons. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an extended comment intended to help OP describe their problem in sufficient detail for others to help.

---

Let's consider only the intersection of the two bars, parametrized by the angle $\theta$ between them.  In the $\theta = 0$ and $\theta = 180°$ cases, the intersection is the unit-width infinite-length bar. In the $\theta = 90°$ case, the intersection is an unit square. For $0 \lt \theta \lt 90°$ and $90° \lt \theta \lt 180°$, the intersection is a parallelogram.

If the width is measured as a diagonal of the intersection – i.e., between the two points where the edges on the same side of the two bars intersect –, then you'd have
$$\begin{array}{r|c}
\theta ~ ~ & \text{Width} \\
\hline
0° & 1.00 \\
45° & 1.08 \\
90° & 1.41 \\
135° & 1.08 \\
180° & 1.00 \\
\end{array}$$
where the maximum width is $\sqrt{2} \approx 1.41$.

OP's data is wildly different, indicating the "width" is not measured between the two points where the bars' edges on the same side intersect, but in some other way.  How?  At a fixed angle $\varphi$ with respect to one of the bars, or some other way?  OP needs to clarify this.

---

If we use $\theta$ as the angle between the two bars, such that at $\theta = 0°$ $w = 1$, and at $\theta = 180°$ $w = +\infty$, we have the following situation:

[image: Illustration of two bars]

In the yellow right triangle, the hypotenuse is half the width $w$, the horizontal side is half, and therefore
$$\frac{ ~ \frac{1}{2} ~ }{ ~ \frac{w}{2} ~ } = \frac{1}{w} = \cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) \quad \iff \quad w = \frac{1}{\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)}$$

Some numerical values:
$$\begin{array}{r|r}
\theta ~ ~  & w ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ \\
\hline
0° & 1.000000 \\
15° & 1.008629 \\
30° & 1.035276 \\
45° & 1.082392 \\
60° & 1.154701 \\
75° & 1.260472 \\
90° & 1.414214 \\
105° & 1.642680 \\
120° & 2.000000 \\
135° & 2.613126 \\
150° & 3.863703 \\
165° & 7.661298 \\
\end{array}$$

Comment: Thank you for the extra clarification first off, I'm not very good at math lingo. I think you are right about my data being sketchy, however I don't understand how you are getting your value for 45˚. I quickly did some incredibly basic testing and got this. https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLYKj.png

Comment: @JulianH: By measuring the *other* way.  Are you always measuring the longer of the two diagonals of the intersection?

Comment: I'm always measuring from the same two points created by the intersection of the bars (the length of the vector they create). In other words: I'm always measuring from where the angle is made like in the picture above.

Comment: @JulianH: Ah, I think I see now.  In that case, replacing values $w$ either above or below 90˚, depending on which pair of points you choose originally, with $1/w$ should yield the correct result.  Choosing the easier pair, the equation is simply $w = 1 / \cos(\theta/2)$, where $0 \le \theta \lt 180˚$.  At $\theta = 180˚$, $w = \infty$.

Comment: Omg ur a legend, thanks for sticking with me!!! Mad helpful!